# How to ignore passed directory in find command directory search?

Tags: find

I'm trying to perform the same process on all **subdirectories**.  This should **exclude** the current directory, but I'm still matching on that and I don't know why.

```
# Make a dummy file tree to test with
mkdir d d/d{1..3}

find ./d -type d -exec bash -c "echo '{}'" \;

d/
d/d1
d/d2
d/d3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is a directory and (`-type d`) so it gets printed. You can try to set the minimum depth

```
find ./d -mindepth 1 -type d
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the max and min subdirectory depths.

```
find ./d -mindepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c "echo '{}'" \;
```